# Structuring table to accept unique comments using PDO

Tags: php, unique

How do I structure my table so it will not accept double "same" comments from the same name for a particular post, while allowing a user to comment with the same comment and name under another post?

`$con->query("create table comment(id int(11) not null auto_increment, post_id varchar(20) not null, comment varchar(1000) not null, name varchar(20) not null, date datetime not null, primary key(id))");`

Comment: You can check if name,post_id and comment match and I would suggest for you to use id_post as int and use id_user instead of name if you have tables for that.

Comment: Thanks at marko..i did not think i that direction...thankx man..(post id contains alphabets and numbers...and no special table for users )..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNIQUE KEY`  to define unique together on id, name and comment. doing this mysql will not allow the same combination to be inserted in the table. try

```
$con->query("create table comment(id int(11) not null auto_increment, post_id varchar(20) not null, comment varchar(1000) not null, name varchar(20) not null, date datetime not null, primary key(id),UNIQUE KEY `unique_together` (`id`,`name`,`comment`))");
```

hope it helps :)